# Can't access a server over pfsense VPN while its connected to PIA VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, pfsense

I have a VPS connected to my homelab that is connected to a VPN via Private Internet Access. The VPN is designed to be "always on".

It has network interfaces:

```
root@chocobo:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether ca:3e:20:1c:7a:9d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.10.0.76/24 brd 10.10.0.255 scope global ens18
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::c83e:20ff:fe1c:7a9d/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
link/none
inet 10.43.17.6 peer 10.43.17.5/32 scope global tun0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::94f2:c4aa:7dcb:975b/64 scope link flags 800
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

It does have a VPN killswitch enabled via ufw.

My local LAN network is in the 10.10.0.0/24 subnet.
My PFSense VPN is in the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet.

For what its worth I also have a 10.10.100.0/24 and 10.10.250.0/24 subnets for smart home devices and guest network devices, respectively (both are controlled via VLAN's).

I know this is a routing issue but I'm not sure how to solve it.

I can't connect to this VPS while its connected to the PIA VPN. If I turn the PIA VPN off, it works just fine (even while the UFW firewall is on).

The UFW firewall:

```
root@chocobo:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10.10.0.0/24               ALLOW       Anywhere
199.116.115.142 1194/udp   ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW       Anywhere
199.116.115.142 1198/udp   ALLOW       Anywhere
10.0.0.0/8                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       10.10.0.0/16
10.10.0.0/16               ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere (v6) on tun0      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

10.10.0.0/24               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
199.116.115.142 1194/udp   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
199.116.115.142 1198/udp   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
10.0.0.0/8                 ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   10.10.0.0/16
10.10.0.0/16               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
```

Additionally in my VPN Server configuration in pfsense I have "push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.255.0"" and I can access everything else over the VPN, just not this server connected to the VPN.

If I can I'd rather have this be fixed server side instead of client, either the VPN server or the PIA VPN client.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If pfsense uses port forwarding many of the PIA servers do not port forward, you have to find a PIA server that does.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So are you trying to connect from the VPS to your homelab / own VPN server *via* the PIA VPN tunnel (like a tunnel in a tunnel)? Or do you want them to work paralelly?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an issue with the UFW "killswitch"? I mean usually that's exactly the point of this feature – to prevent any non-VPN communications.

Comment: Also, please see https://superuser.com/questions/1502393/multiple-nics-in-linux-how-to-return-route-through-established/1503160 – I'm not closing as duplicate because that thread's accepted answer uses RH/CentOS-specific configuration files, but the general idea (the need for source-based routing) is exactly the same.